# Xlib, strings of different font size, c

Tags: c, string, fonts, xlib

I draw 2 strings, I want the 2nd to have bigger font size. This is the, partial, code I use:

```
XFontStruct* font;
char* name = "-*-dejavu sans-bold-r-*-*-*-220-100-100-*-*-iso8859-1";
font = XLoadQueryFont(dpy, name);
XSetFont(dpy, gc, font->fid);
XTextExtents(font, msg, len, &dir, &ascent, &descent, &overall);
XDrawString(dpy,w,gc, (width-XTextWidth(font, msg, strlen(msg)))/2, y-ascent, msg, strlen(msg));
XDrawString(dpy,w,gc, (width-XTextWidth(font, msg2, strlen(msg2)))/2, y-ascent, msg2, strlen(msg2));
```

How could I do that ?

Comment: set a different font before drawing the second string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works ( @luser droog was right ), not sure if there is a better way.

```
XFontStruct* font;
char* name = "-*-dejavu sans-bold-r-*-*-*-220-100-100-*-*-iso8859-1";
font = XLoadQueryFont(dpy, name);
XSetFont(dpy, gc, font->fid);
XTextExtents(font, msg, len, &dir, &ascent, &descent, &overall);
XDrawString(dpy,w,gc, (width-XTextWidth(font, msg, strlen(msg)))/2, y-ascent, msg, strlen(msg));
XSetFont(dpy, gc, font2->fid);    
XDrawString(dpy,w,gc, (width-XTextWidth(font, msg2, strlen(msg2)))/2, y-ascent, msg2, strlen(msg2));
```

Comment: The arguably better way is to ditch server side fonts in favour of Xft, [as recommended by Xorg](https://www.x.org/wiki/guide/fonts/). And perhaps bare Xlib coding as well.

Comment: Thanks, what are pro and con of server side font ? my priority is efficency.

Comment: I know nothing about efficiency of either approach, you probably want to measure and compare